# Handling Backbone.model.destroy with server-side authentication

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

What is the common practice when dealing with `Backbone.js` and server-side permission based **RESTful** interactions.

For example if a user wants to remove a model from a view, but needs certain permissions, given how `model.destroy()` works (even with the wait option set to true).

In order to stop the model from being removed  / delete I would have to make sure the `{wait: true}` option is set and  throw a non 200 status code from the server so that the `destroy({error: function(){})` callback is used.

Is there another way around this that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You understand it correctly.

When passing `{wait:true}` you trigger the `destroy` event in the `success` callback.

`Is there a way around it...?`

If you wanted to change the behavior of the `destroy` method, sure.